# Java button layout right allign

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

Please could someone provide a little insight into my code. I am wanting to get the button on the balance tab to be aligned to the top left.  I have tried different layout managers but all seem to result in the same or similar result of the button being in the center

```
public class DefaultView extends JFrame {

    public DefaultView() {    
        JButton SendBalInc = new JButton();
        SendBalInc.setText("Balance");    
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        // Bal.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;    
        JPanel window = new JPanel();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800, 600);
        // this.setUndecorated(true);    
        window.setBackground(Color.WHITE);    
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);    
        JComponent panel1 = makeTextPanel("Panel #1");
        tabbedPane.addTab("PIN ", panel1);    
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());    
        box.add(SendBalInc);    
        panel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);    
        panel2.add(box);    
        tabbedPane.addTab("Balance", panel2);    
        JComponent panel3 = makeTextPanel("Panel #3");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Dep", panel3);    
        JComponent panel4 = makeTextPanel("Panel #4");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Bill", panel4);    
        window.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        window.add(tabbedPane);    
        this.add(window);    
    }

    protected JComponent makeTextPanel(String text) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        return panel;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Isn't `new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT)` set on a `JPanel` and then adding it at the `PAGE_START` location of another `JPanel` with `BorderLayout`, working for this case? A small working example or a simple diagram of expected result, will be much appreciated, from your side :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer GridBagLayout:

```java
    final JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    panel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    final GridBagConstraints cons = new GridBagConstraints();
    cons.weightx = 1D;
    cons.weighty = 1D;
    cons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    panel2.add(box, cons);

    tabbedPane.addTab("Balance", panel2);
```

note: box is not needed

Comment: ok so its in the top left corner, thanks. is there any particular reason why you have to use weight to get it in the corner and gridx/ gridy dont work ?

Comment: This is described well in JavaDoc ;-) - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html: `Used to determine how to distribute space, which is important for specifying resizing behavior. Unless you specify a weight for at least one component in a row (weightx) and column (weighty), all the components clump together in the center of their container. This is because when the weight is zero (the default), the GridBagLayout object puts any extra space between its grid of cells and the edges of the container.` (better description comparing to GridBagConstraints#weightx)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use BoxLayout

```
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
panel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
panel2.add(SendBalInc);
```

But I think that Betlista's answer with GridBag may be preferable, since you have many more options to tweak the layout further in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Create the Box and add it directly to the JTabbedPane, rather than putting it in a panel first. And make the box a vertical box, so that you can control the alignment of its children by setting setAlignmentX on each child.

```
    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    box.add(SendBalInc);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Balance", box);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to alligh the button to the left:

`panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));`

You can find more in documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html